# Rails 5: Respond to AJAX call with HTML (instead of javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

*(Rails version 5.1.2)*

I would like to respond to AJAX with HTML rather than javascript for much the same reasons as outlined in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21043068/returning-html-to-ajax-rails-calls) stack overflow question.

However, I can't actually get it to work.

I'm using `form_for` with `remote: true` to send the request via AJAX.  Note that I've also experimented with `data: {type: :html}`.

My controller action has the line `render layout: !request.xhr?` and has an associated view.  It's this view that I want sent back to the client.

Yet the client-side code:

```
$("form").on('ajax:success', (e, data, status, xhr) ->
  console.log xhr.responseText #using console.log data produces same result
)
```

Gives:

```
Turbolinks.clearCache()
Turbolinks.visit("http://localhost:3000/...", {"action":"replace"})
```

Where's the HTML?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure I understand what you are attempting to do, but could you not render the HTML server side and return it on the AJAX call response?

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do.

Comment: As the linked question mentions, why don't you avoid the remote form and simply do the AJAX call yourself from javascript, receive the html as string from Rails and then append it to your HTML?

Answer (score 1):

Unless I am completely misunderstanding what you want to do, this should be what you are looking for:

**Javascript**:

```
$.ajax({
  // remember to add this route to your routes file
  url: "products/ajax_render",
  success: function(data){
    $('.some_div').html(data['html'])
  },
});
```

**Ruby on Rails**:

```
def ajax_render
  # render some view and store it in a variable
  html = render "products/your_view"

  # return it inside the json response
  render json: { html: html }
end
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Thanks for responding.  So in your example I just want to return the HTML generated in ajax_render.html.erb back to the client (and then manipulate it on the client side). That's it.  If it was a non-ajax call, I wouldn't need any code at all in the controller action to return the correct HTML. I just don't understand why anything needs doing at all in the controller action, besides possibly disabling the layout. Why, in your answer, did you have to convert the html to json format, and then on the client side re-extract the HTML? Why couldn't you just send the HTML???!!!

Comment: Because when you render the HTML into a variable it's just a string. All we are doing there is send that string as a JSON variable and then append that to the DIV. You are thinking of JSON and HTML as data types, or file types, but in this case HMTL is just a string of characters you are passing on from server to client, and JSON is simply the format you are using to pass that string.